# use rsync with air application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, rsync

I'd like to include into my air application a backup function.
The goal is to copy directory from computer to remove support (usb disk for example).
As main directory contain a lot of sub directory, I thinks to use rsync to synchronise source and destination is a good way.

Why do you think about that, and do you know how to do that with air project.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

In adobe air, you can call out to the command line.  Check [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5d46-8000.html) out.  This should allow you to use rsync.